# DirectX12 GetCurrentBackBufferIndexが0か1を返さない

Tags: c++

お世話になっております。DirectX12でスワップチェーンを生成したのですが、
その後GetCurrentBackBufferIndexが0か1を返さない現象に遭遇しております。

使用ＯＳはwindows 10　64bit
コンパイラは visual studio 2019です

コードは以下の通りです。

```
ウインドウを生成しhwndを作成する
void Window::CreateGameWindow( WNDCLASSEX& windowClass)
{
    auto result = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    m_windowClass.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
    m_windowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    m_windowClass.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) Windowprocedure;
    m_windowClass.lpszClassName = "DirectX12サンプル";
    RegisterClassEx(&m_windowClass);

    RECT wrc = {};
    wrc.left = 0;
    wrc.top = 0;
    wrc.right = window_width;
    wrc.bottom = window_height;
    AdjustWindowRect(&wrc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, false);


    m_hwnd = CreateWindow(
        m_windowClass.lpszClassName,
        "DirectX12",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        wrc.right - wrc.left,
        wrc.bottom - wrc.top,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        m_windowClass.hInstance,
        nullptr
    );

     ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_SHOW);//ウィンドウ表示
}
```

```
スワップチェーンを生成する
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapchainDesc = {};
   swapchainDesc.Width = window.window_width;
   swapchainDesc.Height = window.window_height;
   swapchainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
   swapchainDesc.Stereo = false;
   swapchainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
   swapchainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
   swapchainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_BACK_BUFFER;
   swapchainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
   swapchainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
   swapchainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;
   swapchainDesc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_UNSPECIFIED;
   swapchainDesc.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;


   auto result = m_dxgifactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(
       m_cqueue.Get(),
       hwnd,
       &swapchainDesc,
       nullptr,
       nullptr,
       (IDXGISwapChain1**)(m_swapchain.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf())
   );
```

```
　　　　//Tick処理。 バックバッファインデックスを呼び出す
        auto BbufferIndex = m_swapchain->GetCurrentBackBufferIndex();
```

スワップチェーンの生成が失敗していると思われるのですが、生成時にS_OKを返しており、他にも要因があると思われます。

スワップチェーンが見かけ上成功したかに見えても失敗する要因があれば教えていただければ幸いです

Answer (score 0):

`GetCurrentBackBufferIndex`は[`IDXGISwapChain3::GetCurrentBackBufferIndex`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_4/nf-dxgi1_4-idxgiswapchain3-getcurrentbackbufferindex)のことでしょうか？ だとすると

> ```
>   auto result = m_dxgifactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(
>       m_cqueue.Get(),
>       hwnd,
>       &swapchainDesc,
>       nullptr,
>       nullptr,
>       (IDXGISwapChain1**)(m_swapchain.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf())
>   );
> ```

ここで無理やりC形式キャストしているのが気になります。

```
    ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain1> swapchain1;
    auto result = m_dxgifactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(
        m_cqueue.Get(),
        hwnd,
        &swapchainDesc,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        &swapChain1
    );
    result = swapchain1.As(&m_swapchain);
```

ときちんと`IUnknown::QueryInterface`でキャストするとどうでしょうか？

Comment: QueryInterfaceでキャストしてみましたが、IDXGISwapChain3::GetCurrentBackBufferIndex()はやはり0と1以外の数値を返してしまいますね・・・

Comment: @YKYK 全ての戻り値を確認されていますでしょうか？ 挙げられたコードも変数に保存されず捨てられているように見受けられますが。いずれにも問題ないとしたら、質問文に記載されていない個所に問題があるのかもしれません。

Comment: そうですね。一度初期化周りに関数を実行したら正常に0か1を返しましたので、おそらく今回コードに書いていないルートシグネチャ、あるいはグラフィックスパイプライン、定数バッファに問題があるのではないかと思います。一応問題が絞れたので解決とします。ありがとうございました

Comment: 追記:ルートシグネチャ、定数、頂点、インデックスバッファを生成してもきちんと0か1が返ってきました。ご迷惑をおかけしました